# How to get search result value with regular expressions in word document in vsto

Tags: c#, vsto, office-interop

I am trying to replace some words in a Word document, but the new text replaced varies depending on the search result. How do I get the value of that result and this My code

```
WordApp.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting();
 //Options
matchWholeWord = true;
WordApp.Selection.Find.Text = @"<[0-9]@>";
WordApp.Selection.Find.Forward = true;
WordApp.Selection.Find.Wrap = Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue;
WordApp.Selection.Find.MatchWholeWord = false;
WordApp.Selection.Find.MatchKashida = false;
WordApp.Selection.Find.MatchDiacritics = false;
WordApp.Selection.Find.MatchAlefHamza = false;
WordApp.Selection.Find.MatchControl = false;
WordApp.Selection.Find.MatchAllWordForms = false;
WordApp.Selection.Find.MatchSoundsLike = false;
WordApp.Selection.Find.MatchWildcards = true;
WordApp.Selection.Find.Execute();

var ResultText= ????;//My problem         
string ReplacedText = ResultText.GetNewText();
```

My problem is that I can't get **ResultText**  to be able to create the **Replacedtext** and then do the replacement

Comment: Probably something like; `Word.Range rng = WordApp.Selection; ... rng .FInd.Execute(); var text = rng.Text;`

Comment: `var text = rng.Text;`
This returns all text in Range and does not return text to which Pattern applies Regular Expressions